# Can adding a cache tag create another cache row in database

Tags: 8, caching, breadcrumbs

I want Node breadcrumbs to be updated when the content is updated, so I added the following code to my breadcrumb generation class:

```
// Set cache tags
$node_cache_tag = 'node:'.$node->id();
$breadcrumb->addCacheTags(array($node_cache_tag));
```

My concern is that this is a bad idea for sites with a lot of content (300,000+).  I saw this post https://www.drupal.org/node/2891281 and noted that the default cache row limit is 5,000. Would the above code be an issue with over 300,000 nodes? Should I cache the breadcrumbs based on the taxonomy term that created the breadcrumbs (~1300 terms)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should add tags of all nodes/terms you use to build the breadcrumb. You can't set too many tags, because a tag doesn't influence how many cache entries are stored.

This is only a problem you have by adding cache contexts. By default this is `url.path.parent`. But if you use for example the title of the current node, then you need `url.path`. When you have 300.000 nodes this can indeed make caching quite useless and you could consider setting a cache max-age of 0 to disable caching. Perhaps by doing this you also benefit from lazy loading of the breadcrumb block by Big Pipe, if this is for logged-in users, I've never tried this. And for anonymous users pages are cached for each path anyway.